# Two flyback diodes in parallel for higher current?

Tags: diodes, protection, flyback, fluid-pump

I'm trying to use a water pump that says 12V and 1200mA. I read somewhere that I need to put a flyback diode to handle current when it turns off, but looking around I only have 1N4001 diodes, which can handle 1A max.

Can I put two of those in parallel so each one only have to handle 600mA? Or should I buy a bigger one?

Comment: An 1N4001 will allow a peak surge up to 30A, so you are okay with that slight overcurrent over a very short time.

Comment: @Janka - Ok thanks, didn't realized. Just for my curiosity, in a case where the current were much higher than the diode max peak, would that be a solution? To put as many diodes in parallel as needed? Or is it always better to use only one bigger diode?

Comment: @Enuff Use only one bigger, paralleling any semiconductor device to handle more amps requires additional elements, e.g. resistor in series with every diode/transistor.

Comment: they never share exactly equally, but i don't see a non-faulty diode only grabbing 20% (instead of 50% in a perfect world). temp and load can affect it as well, but you're likely ok. it will also slightly reduce the voltage drop, so make sure that's not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1N400x diodes have a tempco of 100 deg k/W for junction temp rise.
There is no max power rating but temp rise ought to be in the 40'C max range for a decent design.

instantaneous power @1.2A 0.93V @25'C
Max current no-repetitive is 30A.

Since diodes have a NTC cooefficient current sharing can lead to hogging so to remain stable IF the current was continuous would require a series R about equal to the tolerance on the ESR with thermal matching. ESR is about 0.25V/1A = 0.25 Ohms if heatsunk.

So for the pump, no problem.